# .id() method failing on jQuery selector

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

trying to create a function that make's a div slide down depending on it's ID using jquery. 
Trying to get it done as a efficiently as possible.

Here's what I have so far:

```js
$('.meet-the-team').on('click', function() {

               var member = $(this).id();
               var parts = member.split();
               var id = parts[parts.length - 1];

               $(".member-profile #profile" + id).slideDown();

             });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="pure-g meet-the-team">
  <div class="pure-u-1-4 meet-the-team-a" id="member-a">
A
  </div>
  <div class="pure-u-1-4 meet-the-team-b" id="member-a">
B
  </div>
  <div class="pure-u-1-4 meet-the-team-c" id="member-a">
C
  </div>
  <div class="pure-u-1-4 meet-the-team-d" id="member-a">
D
  </div>
</div>
<div class="pure-g member-profile member-profile-a" id="profile-a">
  <div class="pure-u-10-24 member-profile-left">
    <h1>Jordon McCord</h1>
    <h2>Designer/User Experience</h2> 
    <i class="fa fa-linkedin-square fa-6"></i>
  </div>
  <div class="pure-u-14-24  member-profile-right">
    <p>Jordan is a User Interface and User Experience Designer with over 8 years of experience working on a range of exciting projects utilising his key skills in design and front end web development. Jordan is passionate about design and user interactions
      and in his spare time, he really enjoys writing about himself in the third person.</p>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="pure-g member-profile member-profile-b" id="profile-b">
  <div class="pure-u-10-24 member-profile-left">
    <h1>Adam McCord</h1>
    <h2>Designer/User Experience</h2> 
    <i class="fa fa-linkedin-square fa-6"></i>
  </div>
  <div class="pure-u-14-24  member-profile-right">
    <p>Jordan is a User Interface and User Experience Designer with over 8 years of experience working on a range of exciting projects utilising his key skills in design and front end web development. Jordan is passionate about design and user interactions
      and in his spare time, he really enjoys writing about himself in the third person.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Why does this not work?

Thanks in advance for the help guys.

Comment: Side note, IDs **must** be unique.

Comment: Please try to use titles that describe what your problem is (i.e. an error message or a scenario, etc...)

Comment: `$(this)` will refer to the element on which the event is registered `('.meet-the-team')` in this case, not the target of the event.  To get the item that was clicked, try `$(e.currentTarget).prop("id");`  Also, for this to work you need to make your event handler function accept `e` as an argument.

Comment: You should put this in jsfiddle for us to look at.   Also, your .SlideDown -- you don't need to clarify the class then ID, just reference it    $("#profile"+id).SlideDown() -- IDs are unique to the whole page - so there's no need to say "this class with this ID".

Comment: @Jason: They used a stack snippet. This is good enough to let people play with the code.

Comment: oh dagnabit, i'm still getting used to that new feature.   Thanks, @MattBurland

Comment: I'm assuming that's a typo on the ids and they are supposed to be `member-a`, `member-b`, etc and not all `member-a`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('.meet-the-team div').on('click', function() {
    var member = $(this).attr('id');
    var parts = member.split('-');
    var id = parts[parts.length - 1];

    $(".member-profile-" + id).slideDown();
});
```

This should work. You could also use `$("#profile-" + id).slideDown();` instead of the `$(".member-profile-" + id).slideDown();`.

Comment: Thank you, this worked! Learned a lot during this discussion, the learning curve for Javascript is huge.